# C# Entity Framework .ToList() on IQueryable throws an error System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have seen some variants of this issue in the past, but none of them have applied to my issue, so I am starting a new one.

I have a model class `Transactions`. It has a string property `TransactionNumber` like this:

```
public string TransactionNumber { get; set; }
```

It has a column in the database that looks like:

```
TransactionNumber varchar(64) not null,
```

When I try to grab entities that meet criteria like:

```
var transactions = transactionContext.Transactions
   .Where(t => string.Equals(t.TransactionNumber, "15335564-1"));
```

and then try to process those transactions, like so:

```
if (transactions.Any())
{
    foreach (Transaction transaction in transactions.ToList())
    {
        transaction.PaymentStatus = transactionStatus.Status;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
> at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )

I have tried other methods like `FirstOrDefault()` but I get the same error.

I am not really sure where it's looking for an `Int32`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `t.TransactionNumber == "15335564-1"` rather than `string.Equals(t.TransactionNumber, "15335564-1")`.

Comment: EF Core has changed. You can only use `string.Equals` or any other in memory method if the entire collection is in memmory. EF can't translate `string.Equals` to sql

Comment: I should mention that i have used `.Where(t => t.TransactionNumber == "15335564-1")` as part of my tests, with the same results.

Comment: What are you using ? The "classic" EF (EF v6.x) - or EF Core (and which version)? If "classic" EF - is this on the full .NET framework, or running on .NET Core? You've used both tags - which makes it really hard to know which EF variant you're really working with ....

Comment: Can you double check the database in SSMS that the TransactionNumber column is not nullable and doesn't contain any null data?

Comment: @Noobie3001 yes, I have double-checked. that column is not nullable, nor does it contain any null values.

Comment: @marc_s sorry, my bad. I'll fix that tag. I am using EF Core 3.1.9

Comment: If it's not nullable then check that the value you're attempting to assign to it isn't null first.

Comment: Just to make sure I am reading this right, it is throwing the exception when you call the `.ToList()` method correct?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is on that column (TransactionNumber)? `"get_Int32"` make me think of a numeric column: the one you are focusing on contains strings.

Comment: @PatrickMcvay No, the call to `.Any()` would fail first...

Comment: Likely not related to TransactionNumber but to other property of Transaction (since you fetch whole Transaction object). Check all int properties in your model which are not nullable and compare with database, one is likely nullable there, so you have a mismatch between EF model and database

Comment: Seems to me like there is another property which is `int` on your `Transaction` object that's null in your database row and that's why you are getting the exception. The any call does not retrieve data and thus doesn't map the values to properties, whereas tolist does.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, instead of using `.Any()` use `transactions != null`.

Comment: I am thinking the `int` that is referred to in the exception is not what you think. I believe it is part of the `.Any()` method. I think you need to call `ToList()` before you call `Any()`. See this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.common.commandtrees.expressionbuilder.dbexpressionbuilder.any?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Core_Common_CommandTrees_ExpressionBuilder_DbExpressionBuilder_Any_System_Data_Entity_Core_Common_CommandTrees_DbExpression_

Comment: Here is another reference that may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: @PatrickMcvay correct.. this is dying at the `.ToList()` call..

Comment: It looks like @AthanasiosKataras led me to the correct solution. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your class looks like this:

```
public class Transactions {
    public string TransactionNumber { get; set; }
    // some int property
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

Try at first to declare the int properties nullable

```
public class Transactions {
    public string TransactionNumber { get; set; }
    // some int property
    public int? SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

Once you figure out which property is causing the issue, you need to either keep it nullable in your code, or make the reverse action in the database (protect the column so it's never null)

Comment: Thank you, this turned out to be the answer that worked for me. Changing the Ints to nullable allowed me to find a few more problematic fields, but in the end, this is what did it. I didn't know that `.Where()` would enforce database integrity. Thanks again!

Comment: Cheers! Don't forget to accept as solution if indeed it was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works.

```
// Loading it into memory here
var transactions = transactionContext.Transactions
   .Where(t => t.TransactionNumber == "15335564-1").ToList();

// If this does not work try transactions.Count > 0
if (transactions.Any())
{
    foreach (Transaction transaction in transactions)
    {
        transaction.PaymentStatus = transactionStatus.Status;
    }
}
```

If you want to continue to use `string.Equals()` then you can probably use something like the following.

```
// Must Stream results to client first
var transactions = transactionContext.Transactions
   .AsEnumerable().Where(t => string.Equals(t.TransactionNumber, "15335564-1")).ToList();


if (transactions.Any())
    {
        foreach (Transaction transaction in transactions)
        {
            transaction.PaymentStatus = transactionStatus.Status;
        }
    }
```